# Vape cartridge scrutiny at UK customs

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

What kind of scrutiny can I expect from UK customs at an airport if bringing a small vaporizer and one or two cartridges. If the cartridges have nothing like a government seal or list of "ingredients" yet the contents are sealed inside the cartridge so, to assert the contents, they would need to take it apart or actually vape it.

Comment: Just wondering if you can give an update on this.

Comment: I decided not to bring my materials along when we went at the end of last year and sort of just found my way when we got there.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that if you’ve ever used the vaper with any cannabis related products, if their drug sniffer dog gets a whiff of one or two of certain aromatic molecules, or if on physical inspection their swiper spectrometer rings a bell, expect them to give all of your things a very very thorough inspection. Customs are entirely at liberty to destroy items in order to inspect them and they don’t have to compensate you for damage.

Just as an aside, possession of cannabis and cannabis products carry a five year prison term in the UK — I imagine smuggling charges are higher — and then you get deported and banned. Not worth risking it in my opinion.

All around, it’s often easier to just get a new vaper and juice locally than risk any customs issues.

Comment: You seem to be assuming some nefarious intent which I personally don't see any sign of in the question...

Comment: The OP doesn’t note why they are so concerned about the contents of their vape cartridge being inspected. I am making the same inference that a customs officer will make when they see the OP become nervous when the vape device is inspected. Nervous means something is up.

Comment: @amphibient There’s some general guidance here http://cigelectric.co.uk/flying-travelling-with-e-cigarettes/

Comment: In some countries, e-cigarettes are banned entirely. It's quite reasonable to be concerned about this even without cannabis being involved.

Answer (score -6):

Do the following and you will be OK.

1. Disassemble the vaporizer before flying into the UK (ensuring the batteries are out!)
2. You can only carry 100ml of liquid "total" on a plane. Which means you will have to check luggage under the plane if it exceeds 100ml.
3. They go by the 100ml rule by the number on the bottle, not the volume. For example, if you have two bottles that say 100ml, and they’re both only 1/4 full, which would give you 50ml of total liquids, they still go by the 100ml listed on the bottle.

So disassemble the device completely, and if you bring over 100ml of labeled vape juice, check it in a bag under the plane.

Comment: Your point #2 sounds pretty misleading. At least in the EU, the total limit on liquids is close to 1 liter. All your liquids (up to 100 ml per container) need to fit within a 1-liter bag, so the sum of their volumes will inevitably be a little lower, but still much more than 100 ml.

Comment: As someone who fly's their about every other month for years, going in isn't much of a pain as going out. When you fly out, they will check how much liquids you are trying to bring onboard (not checked). If the sum of the labels of the bottles is over 100ml, they will most likely pull you to a side room. Since Brexit, customs is very painful. A friend came with me on my last trip, and brought back two snow globes (both roughly 100ml~ of water each) and they pulled him to the back for interrogation for 1+ hour. I might note this check applies to going through security/customs.

Comment: Brexit hasn't happened yet. Security inspection before boarding has been like that since shortly after 9/11.

Comment: @RedHatcc Sorry but it is categorically not true that you can only take 100ml of liquids in your carry-on. 100ml is the limit for a single container; you're not allowed anything like a half-full 200ml container. You can bring as many separate containers as you can fit inside a single one-litre bag. The rules are essentially identical to the ones used by the USA, except they use American units (3.4floz if 100ml and a quart is roughly a litre).